# JavaFX CSS styling TableView Cell on edit

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview, cell

I'm trying to change the `CSS style` of an `TableView Cell` when I am changing the text but I can't find any selector for that.
On the image you can see the white/blue border, that is what I want to change.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the css you have that is relevant to the `TableView`? Are you using a `TextFieldTableCell` or your own `TableCell` implementation?

Comment: Here is the CSS I use (mostly copied from the caspian.css): http://pastebin.com/0BwCEzdT . And yes I'm using TextFieldTableCell.

Comment: The posted CSS looks a bit different like the picture I posted - I managed to change it so that the white border is a blue border. But just with try and error I still not got the right selector for it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question this week. This is how I solved it:

```
.text-field-table-cell .text-field {
   -fx-padding: 1; 
   -fx-border-color:red; 
   -fx-background-color:yellow;
}
.table-cell:focused {
   -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

This also prevents a change in the row height.

Normal mode:

[image]

Edit mode:

[image]

If you are interested in the focus color, you should take a look at modena.css. There you'll find e. g.

```
/* A bright blue for the focus indicator of objects. Typically used as the
 * first color in -fx-background-color for the "focused" pseudo-class. Also
 * typically used with insets of -1.4 to provide a glowing effect.
 */
-fx-focus-color: #f25f29;
-fx-faint-focus-color: #f25f2933;
```

Comment: Yes, today. But it's a messy one. You have to toy around with the padding. Setting the padding to 2 stretches the TextField and it appears okay. If you set a border color, then the default border size of 1 applies and you'll have to set the padding to 1. And then there's still a 1 pixel gray line on top and left. I just noticed that the default colors have it as well, if you look closely at the inner border in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the blue border or the background, you can try changing the properties of `TextFieldTableCell`. I can manage to change the blue border to red by doing this :

```
TextFieldTableCell > * {
    -fx-border-color: red;
}
```

You can also change the color of the inside of the focused cell (when writing in it) by changing the background color of `TextFieldTableCell > *:focused`.

I think the white border you mention is the regular color for the selection of a cell (`:select`). You can change it by changing the color of the selection when not focused : `.table-row-cell:selected`.

I ended up with this css to change the white border, the blue one and the backgrounds (both focused and unfocused) :

```
// blue border
TextFieldTableCell > * { // when editing
    -fx-background-color: purple;
    -fx-border-color: red;
}

// focused black background
TextFieldTableCell > *:focused { // when editing and clicking in the field
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}

// white border
.table-row-cell:selected { // normal selection (not focused) color
    -fx-background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

Note : in my example, the purple color is only visible when I click outside the editing field, it's the unfocused background color.